# is finite product of complete metric spaces is the same as completion of finite product?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

The following question seems trivial, but I want to make sure I do not have a mistake. Suppose I  have $X,Y$ metric spaces. Denote $\overline{X\times Y}$ the completion of the product. If $\overline{X}$ and $\overline{Y}$ are the completions of each individual space, is it true to say that $\overline{X\times Y}=\overline{X}\times \overline{Y}$?

Comment: What metric are you putting on the product?

Comment: Let's say the max of the two metrics

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543791/the-closure-of-a-product-is-the-product-of-closures

Comment: Nigel, is this equivalent to what I asked here? I am not 100% sure.