# If a line goes through the boundary of a convex set, does that line intersect with exactly two boundary points of the convex region?

Tags: locally-convex-spaces

I have found the following theorem that is often cited from the text Convex Figures by Yaglom and Boltyanskii:

A bounded figure in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is convex iff every straight line
passing through an arbitrary interior point of the figure intersects
the boundary of the figure in exactly two points.

I cannot find the text, nor a proof of this statement, but it seems like it would generalize to higher dimensions.  Is this true?

Comment: You can find one part of the reference [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7FBn.png). By the way, using [these](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202378) [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7376), one can assume that the figure is closed.

Comment: The implication $\implies$ should remain true in higher dimensions.

Comment: @Watson what is the reference there?

Comment: @Prototank : if you mean the first link I gave, it's from _Convex Figures_
by I.M. Yaglom and V.G. Boltyanskii.