# Existence of convergent sequence in a closed set?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Is it true that if $C$ is a closed set, and $x \in {C}$ then there **exist** a sequence $\{x_i\}$ which tends to $x$?

I'm not sure about the correctness of this statement, and whether it is true for every point in the set $C$ or for certain points only (boundary points?). And of course - why is it true? under which conditions?

Comment: Constant sequence $\{x_i \} = \{x \}$ ?

Comment: The sequence $x_n=x$ for all $n$ tends to $x$. But if you mean a sequence with $x_n\ne x$ for all $n$, then the answer is no. For example, the set $\{1\}$ contains all its limit points, so it is closed.

Comment: Oh, do you require that the points $x_n$ are in $C$?

Comment: OK I'll try to be a bit more clear about the context:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202378/is-closure-of-convex-subset-of-x-is-again-a-convex-subset-of-x/202380#202380

I'm looking at the first answer and can't figure out the 'exist' part.
feel free to edit my question so my intention will be more clear.

Comment: @TheKeyBoardHero So it seems you do want the $x_i$ in $C$, but you don't care if they are all equal to $x$. So on that basis, yes it is true that there exists a sequence $x_n$ which tends to $x$.

Comment: @TheKeyBoardHero Use the definition of the closure (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(topology)). An element is in the closure of $C$ iff there is a sequence in $C^{\mathbb{N}}$ which converges towards your element

Comment: @almagest I don't quite agree.
In the context I refered to, $x_i \in X$  but the limit $x$ belongs in $\bar{X}$.

Comment: @TheKeyBoardHero Yes, but if $X$ is closed (which is the case for your set in this question), then the closure of $X$ is $X$ itself