# When the boundary of convex set is convex?

Tags: general-topology

I think the boundary of a convex set cannot be convex, since the segment between tow points on the boundary lies inside the convex set, so the boundary does not contain the segment?

Comment: What if every point of the set is a boundary point?

Comment: The boundary is a convex "curve" not "set"

Comment: @postmortes why a circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is convex?

Comment: @Cathy a circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is convex since any segment joining two points in the circle falls again in the circle.

Comment: @AhmadBazzi Let |x-0| = 1 be a circle in R2, I think it's not convex, since (-1, 0)  and -(1, 0) on the circle, and 0 in the line segment between (-1, 0) and (1, 0),  but (0,0) not in the circle

Comment: @XanderHenderson Is there a example of such set?

Comment: a line segment is a convex set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and it is its own boundary.

Comment: @Cathy what is  |x-0| = 1 ? Do you mean a circle centered at the origin and radius 1 ?

Comment: @achillehui Thanks. I get it.

Comment: @Cathy The example that achille hui gives is what I had in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Take $C = [0,\infty) \subset \mathbb R$. This is a convex set whose boundary is $\{0\}$ which is convex.

In $\mathbb R^n$ any affine subspace $A$ of dimension $< n$ is convex and we have $A = bd(A)$. Moreover any affine halfspace $H$ is convex and $bd(H)$ is an affine hyperplane which is convex.

You see that the boundary of a convex set may very well be convex. Analyzing the above examples we see that that the case that $C$ is convex such that $C = bd(C)$ is a *trivial case*. So let us restrict to the case that $C$ has interior points. The halfspace example (including $C = [0,\infty) \subset \mathbb R$) shows that even then $bd(C)$ may be convex.

You do not say anything about $C$, but I guess you consider the case that $C$ is closed (in which case $bd(C) \subset C$). If not, observe that the closure of $C$ is also convex and has the same boundary as $C$. See [Is closure of convex subset of $X$ is again a convex subset of $X$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202378/is-closure-of-convex-subset-of-x-is-again-a-convex-subset-of-x)

Here is a positive result:

If $C$ is compact with non-empty interior, then $bd(C)$ is not convex.

To see this, let $x \in C$ an interior point. Consider any line $L$ through $x$. Since $L$ is convex and closed, the set $D = L \cap C$ is convex and compact. Thus $D$ is a line segment. Its two boundary points are contained in $bd(C)$, but the "open interval" between the boundary points is not contained in $bd(C)$. Thus $bd(C)$ is not convex.