# Convexity Of The Boundary Of Bounded Open Convex Sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

$\;\;\;\;$ Assume $n>1$ and $U$ is a non-empty bounded open convex subset of $\Bbb R^n$. Is it possible that the boundary $\partial U$ of $U$ is also convex or must it be the case that $\partial U$ is not convex ?

$\;\;\;\;$ My intuition immediately says no. [The question was asked by Cathy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3455919/when-the-boundary-of-convex-set-is-convex), but with no mention of openness, boundedness or dimension, and answered today in the affirmative by Achille Hui and Paul Frost using the open interval $(0,\infty)$ in the case $n=1$.

Comment: Look at a half-space. It is the same example, just multiply by the extra factors. $(0,+\infty)\times\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. Its boundary is the subspace $\{0\}\times\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$.

Comment: Could it also be bounded? Take into account [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krein%E2%80%93Milman_theorem).

Comment: @conditionalMethod. Thank you for the simple generalization. I was imagining a bounded open convex set (non-empty). It seems clear to me in $\Bbb R^1$ that the boundary is not convex and intuitive for me in $\Bbb R^n$ but I want a simple proof.

Comment: @Matthew Daly. Sorry about the confusion. I am indeed asking a different question.

Comment: Well, the proof is not so simple. If the set is bounded, then its closure is convex and compact. By Krein-Milman, its boundary's closed convex hull is the entire set. But if the boundary is convex, then the set is its own boundary. This cannot be for a set with non-empty interior.

Comment: @conditionalMethod. Thanks. I think that was pretty straightforward even though you employed the Krein-Milman Theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose $x$ be a point on the interior of $U$ (since it was given to be open and nonempty, it must have a non-empty interior).  Consider any line $\ell$ that passes through $x$.  This line must intersect $\partial U$ on each side of $x$ since $U$ is bounded.  Choose $y,z$ to be such points on either side of $x$.  Then $y,z\in\partial U$, but $[y,z]\not\subset\partial U$ since $x\in[y,z]$ and $x\not\in\partial U$.  Therefore $\partial U$ is not convex.