# Prove that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x ∈ R$.

Tags: analysis

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function such that $f(r) = 0$ for all rational numbers r. Prove
that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x ∈ R$.

Comment: Use the property that the rationals are dense in the reals.

Comment: Note that [rational numbers are totally disconnected](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Rational_Numbers_are_Totally_Disconnected/Proof_1).

Answer (score 4):

By definition of the real numbers, any real number is limit of a sequence of rational numbers.  Continuous functions preserve limits.

Comment: This answer is commensurate with the level of the question and very probably the kind of solution the lecturer is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like the following **equivalent** definition of continuity is very suitable here:

$$f \textrm{  is continuous}\ \iff f(\overline{M})\subset \overline{f(M)} \textrm{  for all}\ M\subset X $$

Now choose $M=\mathbb Q$ and you are done.

A proof of the above alternative definition of continuity can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114462/continuity-and-closure).