# Equivalent condition for normal topological space

Tags: general-topology

I want to prove the following proposition:

> Let $X$ be a Hausdorff topological space such that $X$ is a normal
>   (i.e., Hausdorff and such that disjoint closed subsets can be
>   separated by open sets) $\Leftrightarrow$ for every closed subset $A$
>   of $X$, for every (open) neighbourhood $U$ of $A$ there exist an open
>   neighbourhood $V$ of $A$ such that $\bar{V} \subseteq U$.

**My attempt**

I'm trying to do the right implication. Let $A$ be closed, $U$ be an open neighbourhood of $A$. Then $B=U^c$ is closed. Both $A$ and $B$ as closed subset of a Hausdorff space are therefore compact and disjoint, therefore by normality they can be separated by two disjoint open sets $U_A,U_B$. My intuition would be to try to prove that the required $V$ is $U_A$. I would only need to prove $\bar{V} \subseteq U$. I can't really go on from here, can anybody give me a hint on how to proceed?

Comment: How do you know that $B$ is compact?

Comment: You're right, I don't know this, do you have a hint to prove the implication anyways?

Comment: Your definition of normal is wrong: in **any** Hausdorff space we can separate disjoint  compact subsets by open sets. So your "normal" is just Hausdorff. Normal is usually defined as being able to separate two disjoint **closed** subsets of $X$, maybe in combination with Hausdorff, that depends.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$X$ is normal if and only if $A\subseteq U$ implies there exists $V$ such that $A\subseteq V\subseteq\overline{V}\subseteq U$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2418392/x-is-normal-if-and-only-if-a-subseteq-u-implies-there-exists-v-such-that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of $X$ being normal is that given disjoint *closed* sets $A$ and $B$ of $X$ there exists disjoint open sets containing $A$ and $B$ respectively.

Given $A$ closed and $U$ open containing $A,$ consider $B=X-U$ and apply the hypothesis of normality with $A$ and $B.$

**Edit.** Your $U_A$ works as $V$ since given $b\in B,$ $U_B$ is a neighborhood of $b$ disjoint from $U_A,$ so $\overline{U_A}\subset U.$

Comment: $\forall b\in B=X\setminus U \implies \exists U_b$ neighbourhood of $b$ that is disjoint from $U_A \implies \exists U_b$ neighbourhood of $b$ s.t. $U_b \subseteq X \setminus U_A \implies b \in \text{Ext}A=X\setminus\bar{A}$. Therefore $\bar{A} \subseteq U$?

Comment: You're correct, just a typo on the end: $b\in X\setminus \overline{U_A}$ and therefore $\overline{U_A}\subset U.$

Comment: Right, I wrote the wrong set, thank you