# Basic Topological problem on closed sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, continuity

How can one prove this proposition:

**proposition 5.15:** $f$ is continuous iff $f(\overline{A}) \subset \overline{f(A)}$, where $\overline{A}$ denotes the closure of a set $A.$

It seems to be a small result, but on the chapter on continuity, it just states this proposition, but I have little clue on how to show this is true. I would appreciate the help.

Comment: see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114462/a-map-is-continuous-if-and-only-if-for-every-set-the-image-of-closure-is-contain)

Comment: @rbird Thank you very much for the source, I will try to study the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let, $f:(X,\tau)\rightarrow(Y,\tau')$ be continuous, then for any closed set $F$ in $(Y,\tau')$ $f^{-1}(F)$ is closed in $X$.

Now let $A\subset X$ be any set. Then $\overline{f(A)}$ is a closed set in$(Y,\tau')$ also $f^{-1}(\overline{f(A)})$ is closed in $(X,\tau)$ with, $A\subset f^{-1}(\overline{f(A)})$.

But, $\overline{A}$ is the smallest subset containing $A$. So, $\overline{A}\subset f^{-1}(\overline{f(A)})$ i.e. $f(\overline{A})\subset \overline{f(A)}$.

Comment: That is only one side of it.

Comment: @drhab - did I make any mistake? please edit if necessary

Comment: You did not make a mistake, but what lacks in your answer is a proof of the other side: if $f(\overline A)\subseteq\overline{f(A)}$ for every $A\subseteq X$ then $f$ is continuous.

Comment: oh! yes. sorry for that