# Topology: Homeomorphism between finite complement topology in $\mathbb{R}$ and one of its subspaces

Tags: general-topology

My class notes say that because $U=\mathbb{R}\backslash\{x_1,x_2,..,x_n\}$ has the same cardinality than $\mathbb{R}$, there exists a homeomorphism between:

$(U,T_{cof})$ and $(\mathbb{R},T_{cof})$, where $T_{cof}$ is the finite complement topology.

I initially thought that having the same cardinality is a necessary condition but is not sufficient to have an homeomorphism.  Also, I can't manage to find a homeomorphism between these two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that in general having the same cardinality is not enough (e.g. $[0,1]$ vs $(0,1)$ with Euclidean topology). However in the case of finite complement topology it is enough.

For that consider any bijection $f:X\to Y$ with finite complement topology on both sides. It is continuous because the preimage of a finite set is finite. It is closed because the image of a finite set is finite. These two properties are enough to ensure that $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your answer. However it seems difficult to find a bijection in practice.. (although there must be one because they have the same cardinality!)

Comment: @Pao Yes, having the same cardinality means (by definition) that such bijection exists. Constructing such bijections may or may not be easy. I didn't put much thought into this.

Comment: I think for the continuity of $f$, we should say "because the presage of a infinite set is infinite". The reason is that, if we let $A$ be an infinite set in $Y$, then $[f^{-1}(A)]^c$ may not equal $f^{-1}(A^c)$. So we can't conclude the continuity of $f$ from "the preimage of a finite set is finite".

Comment: @SamWong we can because a subset is closed if and only if it is finite. I'm using "preimage of closed sets" continuity. Also preimage of complement is complement of preimage under bijection.

Comment: @freakish Oh yeah, I didn't see the bijection condition. You are right. I am thinking of the open sets version proposition.

Answer (score 2):

Enumerate a countably infinite subset $\{a_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ of $\mathbb{R}$ for which the first $n$ terms are $x_1$ through $x_n$. Here is an explicit homeomorphism from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow U$ where the latter is endowed with the finite complement topology:

If $x = x_k$, then map $x \mapsto a_{k+n}$; otherwise, use the identity mapping $x \mapsto x$.

I will leave it to you to check that this function is one-to-one [injective] and onto [surjective].

To show that it is continuous, it suffices to show that the inverse image of any closed set is closed. The closed sets in $U$ are exactly finite subsets of $U$; can you show that the inverse image of such a closed subset is also *finite* in $\mathbb{R}$ hence closed in $\mathbb{R}$ under the finite complement topology?

The last step is to show that the inverse of this function is continuous, too; if you can reason out the above, then the last step should be doable, too.

Comment: Thank you! I agree with your answer, except for the step when you mention that closed sets in V are exactly finite subsets of {1,…,N}. In my opinion, closed sets in V must rather contain {1,...,N}.

Comment: @Pao Corrected the typo! The closed sets in $V$ are precisely its finite subsets.

Comment: You have some errors. In your first sentence you talk about a mapping that "does not compute" since, say,  $x_1 \notin U$.

Comment: @CopyPasteIt Thanks! I've edited to avoid that issue (and make the proof a bit more direct).

Comment: Of course on a quick read, we just nod our heads and say, "sure - that looks reasonable!" (for prior version). $\quad \text{  :)   }$

Answer (score 1):

The following is easy to prove:

Proposition 1: Let $X$ be a set endowed with the cofinite topology. The subspace topology on any $Y \subset X$ is identical to the cofinite topology on $Y$.
Proof: Exercise.

Proposition 2: Let $X$ and $Y$ be two cofinite topological spaces. Then any injective mapping $f: X \to Y$ is continuous.
Proof
The proof will be complete if we can show that

$\tag 1 \text{For any } A \subset X, \; f(\overline{A})\subseteq \overline{f(A)}$

(click [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114462/a-map-is-continuous-if-and-only-if-for-every-set-the-image-of-closure-is-contai)).

There are two cases:

Case 1: If $A$ is infinite, $\overline{A} = X$. Since $f$ is injective, $f(A)$ is infinite and $\overline{f(A)} = Y$.
Since $f(X) \subseteq Y$, $\text{(1)}$ must be true.

Case 2: If $A$ is finite, $\overline{A} = A$ and the lhs of $\text{(1)}$ is $f(A)$. The image $f(A)$ is also finite and the rhs of $\text{(1)}$ is also $f(A)$, and so the inclusion relation in $\text{(1)}$ must again be true.$\quad \blacksquare$

Using the above we can now state

Proposition 3: Let $f$ be an injective mapping from a set $X$ with the cofinite topology to a set $Y$ with the cofinite topology. Then $f$ is a homeomorphism between $X$ and its image $f(X)$.

---

Let $U=\mathbb{R}\backslash\{x_1,x_2,..,x_n\}$ for distinct numbers $x_i$ and assume that

$\quad x_n = \text{max(}x_1,x_2,..,x_n\text{)}$

Extend the finite sequence by defining $x_{n+k} = x_n + k$ for $k \ge 1$.

We can define an injection on the set of $x_i$ via

$\quad x_i \to x_{i+n}$

This injection can be easily extended to define a bijective correspondence between $\mathbb R$ and $U$.

Comment: As a piece of trivia: The last idea, for the countably infinite case, dates back at least to the correspondence between Dedekind and Cantor. See Gouvea's AMM [**article**](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/pubs/AMM-March11_Cantor.pdf) (cf. from the second full paragraph on p. 204: bijecting the irrational numbers in the unit interval with the entire unit interval). The finite case of bijecting $(0, 1]$ and $[0, 1]$ is mentioned there, too. [Anyway: +1]