# Continuous function (Topology)

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity

Theorem. Let $f:X\rightarrow{Y}$ be a continuous function. They are equivalent: $f(\overline{A})\subseteq\overline{f(A)}$ for all $A\subseteq X$ iff $f^{-1}(B^{\circ})\subseteq(f^{-1}(B))^{\circ}$ for all $B\subseteq Y$

Proof: Let $ B\subseteq{Y} $ be. Let's see that $f^{-1}(B^{\circ})\subseteq{(f^{-1} (B))^{\circ}} $. Note that $ B^{\circ} = Y\setminus{(\overline{Y\setminus {B}})} $. Then $$ f^{-1}(B^{\circ})= f^{- 1}(Y\setminus {(\overline {Y\setminus{B}})}) = X \setminus{f^{-1} (\overline {Y\setminus{B}})} $$ On the other hand, we have $$ (f^{- 1}(B))^{\circ} = X\setminus {\overline { (X \setminus {f^{- 1} (B)}})} = X \setminus {\overline {f ^ {- 1} (Y \setminus {B})}} $$ Now, let's see that $ \overline {f ^ {- 1} (Y \setminus {B})} \subseteq {f ^ {- 1} (\overline {Y \setminus {B}})} $. Let $ A = f ^ {- 1} (Y \setminus {B}) \subseteq {X} $ be. By hypothesis, we have $$ f (\overline {f ^ {- 1} (Y \setminus {B})}) \subseteq {\overline {f (f ^ {- 1} (Y \setminus {B})) }} \subseteq {\overline {Y \setminus {B}}} $$ For the above, we have $$ \overline {f ^ {- 1} (Y \setminus {B})} \subseteq {f ^ {- 1} (f (\overline {f ^ {- 1} (Y \setminus {B})}))} \subseteq {f ^ {- 1} (\overline {Y \setminus {B}})} $$ Therefore, $$ f ^ {- 1} (B ^ {\circ}) \subseteq {X \setminus {f ^ {- 1} (\overline {Y \setminus {B}})}} \subseteq { X \setminus {\overline {f ^ {- 1} (Y \setminus {B})}}} = {(f ^ {- 1} (B)) ^ {\circ}} $$ Reciprocally, Let $ A \subseteq {X} $ be. Let's see that $ f (\overline {A}) \subseteq {\overline {f (A)}} $. Note that $ \overline {A} = X \setminus {(X \setminus {A}) ^ {\circ}} $. Then $$ f (\overline {A}) = f (X \setminus {(X \setminus {A}) ^ {\circ}}) \subseteq {Y \setminus {f ((X \setminus {A}) ^ {\circ})}} $$ On the other hand, we have $$ \overline {f (A)} = Y \setminus {(Y \setminus {f (A)}) ^ {\circ}} $$ Now , let's see that $ (Y \setminus {f (A)}) ^ {\circ} \subseteq {f ((X \setminus {A}) ^ {\circ})} $. Let $ B = Y \setminus {f (A)} \subseteq {Y} $ be. By hypothesis, we have $$ f ^ {- 1} ((Y \setminus {f (A)}) ^ {\circ}) \subseteq {(f ^ {- 1} (Y \setminus {f (A)} )) ^ {\circ}} $$ Note that $ f ^ {- 1} (Y \setminus {f (A)}) = X \setminus {f ^ {- 1} (f (A))} \subseteq {X \setminus {A}} $. Then $$ f ^ {- 1} ((Y \setminus {f (A)}) ^ {\circ}) \subseteq {(X \setminus {A}) ^ {\circ}} $$ Thus, $ f (f ^ {- 1} ((Y \setminus {f (A)})^ {\circ})) \subseteq {f ((X \setminus {A})^ {\circ})} $

I don't know how to conclude...

Comment: The two conditions are both equivalent to the continuity of $f$.

Comment: @EclipseSun I know. I just want to know if there is a demonstration of that proposition as I wrote it.

Comment: I meant that you don't need to assume $f$ to be continuous at the very beginning.

Comment: @EclipseSun You're right. Leaving that aside, do you know how to do the proof of that theorem? Leaving aside the continuity ...

Comment: cf [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/114462/4280) for one of these properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the link: [Relation between interior and exterior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_(topology)).

Given that $f^{-1}$ exists, so $f$ is bijective and $f$ is given continuous so $f^{-1}$ is open.
Let, $A\subset X$ and $f(\overline A)\subset \overline{f(A)}$ holds.

Now, let $B\subset Y$ then $$B^\circ=Y-\overline{Y-B}\\ \implies f^{-1}(B^\circ)=f^{-1}(Y-\overline{Y-B})\\=X-f^{-1}(\overline{Y-B})\\ \subset X-\overline {f^{-1}(Y-B)}\\=X-\overline{X-f^{-1}(B)}\\=f^{-1}(B)^\circ$$

Now repeat the same process by setting $\overline A=X-(X-A)^\circ$.

Comment: It is *not* given that $f^{-1}$ exists, this is just the notation for the inverse image...

Comment: @SujitBhattacharyya $X-f^{-1}(\overline{Y-B})\subset X-\overline {f^{-1}(Y-B)}$? Why?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma $f^{-1}$ is the inverse image of which map? $f$ of course. That's why I have written that $f^{-1}$ exists.

Comment: For *any* function $f:X \to Y$, $f^{-1}(A)=\{x \in X: f(x) \in A\}$ if $A \subseteq Y$. No need for an inverse function.

Comment: @Darkmaster Set, $f(A)=B\implies A=f^{-1}(B)$, given $f(\overline A)\subset \overline {f(A)}\implies \overline A\subset f^{-1}(\overline {f(A)})\implies \overline{f^{-1}(B)}\subset f^{-1}(\overline B)$. For similarity replace $B$ by $Y-B$ and observe its complement.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thanks for the tip. Let me work on that, I will edit the post if I find a solution under that particular definition. ps: is that true that $f^{-1}(Y)=X$ under the definition ?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma $A=f^{-1}(f(A))$ for all $A\subseteq{X}$ iff f is injective. Also, 
$f^{-1}(\overline{Y-B})=\overline{f^{-1}(\overline{Y-B})} \implies \overline{f^{-1}(Y-B)}\subseteq{f^{-1}(\overline{Y-B})}$.

Comment: Yes, $f^{-1}[Y]=X$ always. And even $f^{-1}[f[\{x\}]] = \{x\}$ for all $x \in A$ is enough for 1-1-ness. Not sure about your last implication, $\overline{A} = \overline{B}$ does not imply $\overline{A} \subseteq B$.....

Comment: $f(A)=B$ does not imply $A=f^{-1}(B)$ (Only $\subseteq$). So that argument fails.

Answer (score 0):

The following two statements about a function $f:X \to Y$ between topological spaces are equivalent:

1. $\forall A \subseteq X: f[\overline{A}] \subseteq \overline{f[A]}$.
2. For all closed $C \subseteq Y$: $f^{-1}[C]$ is closed in $X$.

For 1 implies 2: let $C$ be closed in $Y$. Define $D = f^{-1}[C]$ and apply fact 1 to it: $$f[\overline{D}] \subseteq \overline{f[D]} = \overline{f[f^{-1}[C]]}\subseteq \overline{C} = C$$ as $C$ is closed. But this implies that $\overline{D} \subseteq f^{-1}[C] =D$ (all points of $\overline{D}$ map into $C$) and so $D = f^{-1}[C]$ is closed, as required.

For 2 implies 1: Let $A \subseteq X$ and note we have $$A \subseteq f^{-1}[f[A]] \subseteq f^{-1}[\overline{f[A]}]$$ and by 2. the latter set is closed. Hence 
$\overline{A} \subseteq f^{-1}[\overline{f[A]}]$ as well and this means that $f[\overline{A}]\subseteq \overline{f[A]}$ by the definitions of inverse images.

---

The following two statements about a function $f:X \to Y$ between topological spaces are equivalent:

3. $\forall B \subseteq Y: f^{-1}[B^\circ] \subseteq f^{-1}[B]^\circ$.
4. For all $O \subseteq Y$ open, $f^{-1}[O]$ is open in $X$.

For 3 implies 4: let $O$ be open in $Y$, then $O^\circ = O$ and by 3:
$$f^{-1}[O]= f^{-1}[O^\circ] \subseteq f^{-1}[O]^\circ \subseteq f^{-1}[O]$$
so $f^{-1}[O]^\circ = f^{-1}[O]$ and $f^{-1}[O]$ is open.

For 4 implies 3: if $B \subseteq Y$ is any subset $B^\circ \subseteq B$ so
also $f^{-1}[B^\circ] \subseteq f^{-1}[B]$. The former is an open subset (by 4)  contained in $f^{-1}[B]$ and the interior of a set is its largest open subset so it follows that $f^{-1}[B^\circ] \subseteq f^{-1}[B]^\circ$, as required.

---

Now note that 2 and 4 are clearly equivalent as $f^{-1}[Y\setminus A]= X\setminus f^{-1}[A]$ for all subsets $B$ of $Y$, and open and closed sets are related via complements.

So all conditions are equivalent to $f$ being continuous.

Comment: @SujitBhattacharyya Thanks! You're great!

Comment: @Darkmaster did you mean as a comment to the other answer?