# Restriction of the continuous function in Van der Waerden's theorem

Tags: general-topology, continuity, ramsey-theory

I was reading the book Elemental Methods in Ergodic Ramsey Theory. In the book they define the following:
$$\Omega =\{1,\cdots, r\}^{\mathbb{N}}, \quad T:\Omega \to \Omega \quad \text{ defined by } T\gamma :=T\gamma(n)=\gamma(n+1) $$
$\Omega$ is cleary a metric space with metric $\rho(\gamma,\xi):=\frac{1}{min\{k: \gamma(k)\neq \xi(k)\}}$.

Also, it is clear to me that $T:\Omega\to \Omega$ is continuous. Let $\alpha\in \Omega$  If $X=\overline{\{T^{m}\alpha\mid m\in \mathbb{N}\}}$, then why $T\upharpoonright X$ is a continuous self-map of X? I was trying to prove that $T(X)\subseteq X$ proving that for all $r>0$ $$B(f(x),r)\cap \{T^{m}\alpha\mid m\in \mathbb{N}\}\neq \emptyset$$
but I can not conclude, I would appreciate some guidance for this exercise.

Comment: Hint: Suppose that $f: X\to Y$ is continuous, $A\subset X$. Then $f(cl(A))\subset cl f(A)$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114462/a-map-is-continuous-if-and-only-if-for-every-set-the-image-of-closure-is-contai/114572).